# CURL: Variables not getting sent

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I am trying to convert a javascript (Node.js) script to a PHP script.

```
// Send POST request
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'someurl',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
```

That is the javascript. I have tried to replicate by it by using this code

```
$url = 'something';

$formData = array( 'code'=>$var);
$var = 'somethinghere';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $formData);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $response;
```

However, it doesn't work. It doesn't display the data i wanted. It is an external php file (Not hosted by me), i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Whats [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) say?

Comment: If it is not sensitive, it would help us if you provided the real URL to test with, or at least a dummy but functional URL to test with.

Comment: Is curl enabled on the server? To check- see php.ini file and see if `;` is removed in line `;extension=php_curl.dll`

Comment: Most likely the problem is that `Content-Type` of request is different from what you expected: `multipart/form-data`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It is due to type of `$formData` variable you passed to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option. Quote from [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): _If value (of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS) is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data._

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to say what kind of response you are getting.

Also, you are using $var before it is set, i.e.

$formData = array( 'code'=>$var);
$var = 'something here';

Was it set elsewhere in your code or is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks. It really worked..But i have another problem now. I used json_decode function to convert the output json data like string to json object. To test it, i echoed the decoded object, it just outputs as 'Array' without displaying actual array. When i echo without decoding, it displays json data perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when you echo an array. To see what's in it use var_dump() instead. You may want to use json_decode($var, true) to get your response as an associative array.